# Do logical arguments and set variables with Discord chat input?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

Well, I wanted to create a bot for discord. One part should be, where  the bot thinks of a random number and I have to guess it with 1 try. There is also line 15 to check, if the bot have detected my message.

When I try it out, the bot is getting only to print out text 1 in line 13. Because after typing in dc a random number (after text1 appeared), the bot just do simply nothin. No errors, that's what is confusing me

Question: Can I use input from discord as for example a variable in line 14 up to the end and do logical arguments with it?

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio                                                          #line 5

drone = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@drone.event
async def on_message(message):                                          #line 10
    if message.content.startswith("g"):

        await drone.send_message(message.channel, "text1")
        f = await drone.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content=(int))
        await drone.send_message(message.channel, f)
                                                                        #line 16
        z = random.randint(1, 10)
        if z == f:
            await drone.send_message(message.channel, "text2")           #line 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `content=(int)`. The content tag checks for the *exact* content the message should have. If you want to make sure the user has inputted an integer, try implementing [`check`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) instead.